# Reading JSON data in a shell script

Tags: json, shell, awk, grep

I have a JSON file containing data about some images:

```
{
    "imageHeight": 1536,
    "sessionID": "4340cc80cb532ecf106a7077fc2a166cb84e2c21",
    "bottomHeight": 1536,
    "imageID": 1,
    "crops": 0,
    "viewPortHeight": 1296,
    "imageWidth": 2048,
    "topHeight": 194,
    "totalHeight": 4234
}
```

I wish to process these values in a simple manner in a shell script. I searched online but was not able to find any simple material to understand.

EDIT : What I wish to do with the values ?

I'm using convert (Imagemagick) to process the images. So, the whole workflow is something like. Read the an entry say crop from a line in the json file and then use the value in cropping the image :

convert -crop [image width from json]x[image height from json]+0+[crop value from json]  [session_id from json]-[imageID from json].png [sessionID]-[ImageID]-cropped.png

Comment: I highly rate `jq` for working with JSON in a shell: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Is using python or perl an option? They both have very good support for working with json-files. json-support is not supported natively in either awk, grep or shell.

Comment: You may provide solutions in python also , it might be helpful :)

Comment: ...also, what would you like to do with the values, i.e. what is your expected outcome? Please update your question. Right now we are just guessing.

Comment: @cbuckley Please can you provide an example on how to process a field in a line in the json file

Comment: @actor_vijay there is extensive documentation in the manual. Have a look at the filters, they're really powerful!

Comment: @cbuckley Cool :) I'll check.

Comment: @cbuckley . When I tried using JQ I get command not found ! Any tips ?

Comment: Er, you need to install it? http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: I installed it. Installed it using brew at path /usr/local/Cellar/jq/1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/). For example, to get the `imageHeight`, you can use:

```
jq ".imageHeight" data.json
```

Output:

```
1536
```

---

If you want to store the value in a shell variable use:

```
variable_name=$(jq ".imageHeight" data.json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python-solution

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('json_file')
data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
data['bottomHeight']
```

output:

```
In [28]: pprint(data)
{u'bottomHeight': 1536,
 u'crops': 0,
 u'imageHeight': 1536,
 u'imageID': 1,
 u'imageWidth': 2048,
 u'sessionID': u'4340cc80cb532ecf106a7077fc2a166cb84e2c21',
 u'topHeight': 194,
 u'totalHeight': 4234,
 u'viewPortHeight': 1296}

In [29]: data['bottomHeight']
Out[29]: 1536
```